# Is there any Build management tool for Mercurial Repository?

Tags: mercurial

I would like to know if mercurial provides any in built BUILD tool for building/packaging the source code.

Comment: Does "the source code" mean "Mercurial's source code" or "the source code in any Mercurial repository"?

Comment: Project source code resided under mercurial repository. Not the mercurial source code.

Answer (score 2):

The `hg archive` program can create an archive of your repo's source code (minus all the Mercurial metadata and untracked files). For example, to create a tarball:

```
$ hg archive --prefix=myproject/ --type=tgz ~/myproject.tgz
```

See `hg help archive` for more information on usage and possible options.

Comment: Let me explain in brief here:

Example: (Create hg repo for a single project)
5 folders on root level. 
Each folder belongs to a separate module of that project.
Now I would like to create separate folder say "Install" which will have similar structure of my project install root of production box.
*********
Now my build tool should copy the delta (latest)files to this Install folder and a jar file for all java source code should also be packaged and move to this 'Install' folder.

Comment: If your `.jar` file is tracked by the repo, then you can use Mercurial's `archive` utility to bundle it up, along with the source files; otherwise, you'll have to use another tool. `hg archive` only archives tracked source code, and it archives *all* tracked files in a repo. You can use `archive`'s `--include` and `--exclude` flags to tailor this behavior a bit, though.